# Are there Explainable GNN methods for node regression tasks?

Tags: papers, graph-neural-networks, model-request, explainable-ai, gnn

I am wondering if there are gnn explainable methods for a regression task (e.g., traffic forecasting) where nodes have numerical features and the predicted output is a numerical value. Most of research papers focus on node classification tasks (GNNexplainer etc) but do not specify if these techniques are fit for node-regression tasks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are several GNN-based approaches for tasks like traffic speed prediction or railway delay prediction, which are doing time-series regression on nodes.

For example:

[T-GCN: A Temporal Graph ConvolutionalNetwork for Traffic Prediction](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.05320)

[Railway Delay Prediction with Spatial-Temporal Graph Convolutional Networks](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9294742)

Comment: Thank you for your response, my question is actually for Explainable GNN frameworks for a temporal task like traffic forecasting such as GNNexplainer or GraphSVX.